# canvas not responding to touch when inside a div on ios safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get a nice knob/dial that can be rotated to send a value back to the server via websockets.
The basic premise works well, I got the code from the web.
I am trying to modify the code so that I get a prettier knob. I've been successful by placing the canvas inside a couple of divs which display static images, while the canvas rotates a translucent image in response to mouse/touch events.
The additions that I made to the code work well on the desktop (I'm running Firefox 45.0.2) but do not work at all on an iPad (Safari, iOS 9.3.5) and only partially on an iPhone (iOS 10.2.1)
On the iPhone, the knob rotates in the opposite direction to that expected, and often only horizontal movement will start the knob rotating.
I'm not using (nor do I want to use) any libraries such as jquery.
The code below will work as is. However, removing the comment marks in the body section will cause the problems I indicated.
(Oh and to forestall any comments, the black background and odd text colour is just there to so that you can see the translucent element without the static backgrounds)
I'm not at all experienced with jscript and can only just manage to follow what the code is doing at the moment. (one of the reasons I don't want to use additional libraries)
I suspect that the problem lies with how the touch event coordinates are interpreted, but I can't test them in any way.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

---

HTML Code:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stepper example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7">
    <style>
      body { 
        text-align: center; background-color: black;
        color: red
      }

      .container{
        position: relative;
        background: url(step_background.png);
        width: 480px;
        height: 480px;
        margin: auto;
        z-index:1;
      }

      .knob{
        position: relative;
        top: 59px;
        background: url(knob_bg.png);
        width: 362px;
        height:362px;
        margin:auto;
        z-index:2;
      }

      #stepper{
        position: relative;
      }

    </style>

    <script>
      var MIN_TOUCH_RADIUS = 20;
      var MAX_TOUCH_RADIUS = 200;
      var CANVAS_WIDTH = 362, CANVAS_HEIGHT = 362;
      var PIVOT_X = 181, PIVOT_Y = 181;
      var plate_angle = 0;
      var plate_img = new Image();
      var click_state = 0;
      var last_angle_pos = 0;
      var mouse_xyra = {x:0, y:0, r:0.0, a:0.0};
      var ws;
      plate_img.src = "knob_fg.png";

      function init() {
        var stepper = document.getElementById("stepper");
        var ctx = stepper.getContext("2d");
        stepper.width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
        stepper.height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
        stepper.addEventListener("touchstart", mouse_down);
        stepper.addEventListener("touchend", mouse_up);
        stepper.addEventListener("touchmove", mouse_move);
        stepper.addEventListener("mousedown", mouse_down);
        stepper.addEventListener("mouseup", mouse_up);
        stepper.addEventListener("mousemove", mouse_move);
        ctx.translate(PIVOT_X, PIVOT_Y);
        rotate_plate(plate_angle);
      }

      function connect_onclick() {
        if(ws == null) {
          ws = new WebSocket('ws://'+ window.location.hostname + ':81/', ['arduino']);
          document.getElementById("ws_state").innerHTML = "CONNECTING";
          ws.onopen = ws_onopen;
          ws.onclose = ws_onclose;
          ws.onmessage = ws_onmessage;
          ws.onerror = function(){ alert("websocket error " + this.url) };
        }
        else
          ws.close();
      }

      function ws_onopen() {
        document.getElementById("ws_state").innerHTML = "<font color='blue'>CONNECTED</font>";
        document.getElementById("bt_connect").innerHTML = "Disconnect";
        rotate_plate(plate_angle);
      }

      function ws_onclose() {
        document.getElementById("ws_state").innerHTML = "<font color='gray'>CLOSED</font>";
        document.getElementById("bt_connect").innerHTML = "Connect";
        ws.onopen = null;
        ws.onclose = null;
        ws.onmessage = null;
        ws = null;
        rotate_plate(plate_angle);
      }

      function ws_onmessage(e_msg) {
        e_msg = e_msg || window.event; // MessageEvent
        plate_angle = Number(e_msg.data);
        rotate_plate(plate_angle);
        //alert("msg : " + e_msg.data);
      }

      function rotate_plate(angle) {
        var stepper = document.getElementById("stepper");
        var ctx = stepper.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(-PIVOT_X, -PIVOT_Y, CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        ctx.rotate(-angle / 180 * Math.PI);
        ctx.drawImage(plate_img, -PIVOT_X, -PIVOT_Y);
        ctx.rotate(angle / 180 * Math.PI);
        /*
            Currently, the angle displayed and sent as a message appears to be set such that movement in a clockwise direction
            reports a negative number. Needs to be looked at, probably by changing "angle.toFixed" to "-angle.toFixed"
        */
        if(ws && (ws.readyState == 1))
          ws.send(plate_angle.toFixed(4) + "\r\n");
        ws_angle = document.getElementById("ws_angle");
        ws_angle.innerHTML = angle.toFixed(1);
      }

      function check_update_xyra(event, mouse_xyra) {
        var x, y, r, a;
        var min_r, max_r, width;
        if(event.touches) {
          var touches = event.touches;
          x = (touches[0].pageX - touches[0].target.offsetLeft) - PIVOT_X;
          y = PIVOT_Y - (touches[0].pageY - touches[0].target.offsetTop);
        }
        else {
          x = event.offsetX - PIVOT_X;
          y = PIVOT_Y - event.offsetY;
        }
        /* cartesian to polar coordinate conversion */
        r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        a = Math.atan2(y, x);
        mouse_xyra.x = x;
        mouse_xyra.y = y;
        mouse_xyra.r = r;
        mouse_xyra.a = a;
        if((r >= MIN_TOUCH_RADIUS) && (r <= MAX_TOUCH_RADIUS))
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }

      function mouse_down(event) {
        if(event.target == stepper)
          event.preventDefault();
        if(event.touches && (event.touches.length > 1))
          click_state = event.touches.length;
        if(click_state > 1)
          return;
        if(check_update_xyra(event, mouse_xyra)) {
          click_state = 1;
          last_angle_pos = mouse_xyra.a / Math.PI * 180.0;
        }
      }

      function mouse_up() {
        click_state = 0;
      }

      function mouse_move(event) {
        var angle_pos, angle_offset;
        if(event.touches && (event.touches.length > 1))
          click_state = event.touches.length;
        if(!click_state || (click_state > 1))
          return;
        if(!check_update_xyra(event, mouse_xyra)) {
          click_state = 0;
          return;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        angle_pos = mouse_xyra.a / Math.PI * 180.0;
        if(angle_pos < 0.0)
          angle_pos = angle_pos + 360.0;
        angle_offset = angle_pos - last_angle_pos;
        last_angle_pos = angle_pos;
        if(angle_offset > 180.0)
          angle_offset = -360.0 + angle_offset;
        else
          if(angle_offset < -180.0)
            angle_offset = 360 + angle_offset;
        plate_angle += angle_offset;
        rotate_plate(plate_angle);
      }

      window.onload = init;

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h2>
      Smart Expansion / Stepper Motor<br><br>
      Angle <font id="ws_angle" color="blue">0</font><br><br>
<!--
      <div class="container">
        <div class="knob">
-->
          <canvas id="stepper"></canvas>
<!--
        </div>
      </div>
-->

      <br><br>
      WebSocket <font id="ws_state" color="gray">CLOSED</font>
    </h2>

    <p><button id="bt_connect" type="button" onclick="connect_onclick();">Connect</button></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

---

I might need to add an additional comment to give the link to the backgound image

[knob_bg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBe5s.png)
[knob_fg.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jACCr.png)

Comment: For whatever reason, I can only and the link to the last image used in the code in this comment. [step_background.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgEK4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after managing to find out how to debug html on an ios device via firefox on windows, I have managed to find out what was causing my code to fail.
The problem was in the function check_update_xyra(event, mouse_xyra)
Specifically the lines :
`x = (touches[0].pageX - touches[0].target.offsetLeft) - PIVOT_X;
y = PIVOT_Y - (touches[0].pageY - touches[0].target.offsetTop);`
The target.offsetxxx was returning a value of 0. This made the radian value (r) to be out of bounds which caused the function to return false, or in the case of the iPhone caused the touch event to behave strangely.
The reason for for the offsets coming back as 0 was because I did not factor in the fact that they provided the offset from the targets parent only, not the document as a whole.
I managed to fix this by adding some code to add the offsets for all parent elements then used that sum to calculate new x and y coordinates. 
My code change follows.
However, if anyone has a more elegant method of calculating the offsets, I would appreciate it.
Cheers...

---

```
function check_update_xyra(event, mouse_xyra) {
  var x, y, r, a;
  var tgtoffleft = 0;
  var tgtofftop = 0;
  var min_r, max_r, width;
  if(event.touches) {
    var touches = event.touches;
    // Bit of code to calculate the actual Left and Top offsets by adding offsets 
    // of each parent back through the hierarchy
    var tgt = event.touches[0].target;
    while (tgt) {
      tgtoffleft = tgtoffleft + tgt.offsetLeft;
      tgtofftop = tgtofftop + tgt.offsetTop;
      tgt = tgt.offsetParent;
    }
    // x = (touches[0].pageX - touches[0].target.offsetLeft) - PIVOT_X;
    // y = PIVOT_Y - (touches[0].pageY - touches[0].target.offsetTop);
    x = (touches[0].pageX - tgtoffleft) - PIVOT_X;
    y = PIVOT_Y - (touches[0].pageY - tgtofftop);
  }
  else {
    x = event.offsetX - PIVOT_X;
    y = PIVOT_Y - event.offsetY;
  }
  /* cartesian to polar coordinate conversion */
  r = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  a = Math.atan2(y, x);
  mouse_xyra.x = x;
  mouse_xyra.y = y;
  mouse_xyra.r = r;
  mouse_xyra.a = a;
  if((r >= MIN_TOUCH_RADIUS) && (r <= MAX_TOUCH_RADIUS))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}
```

---